# Django - Cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to retrive some data stored with models.

models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^all$', 'about.views.all_contacts'),
    url(r'^$', 'about.views.index')
]
```

views:

```
from models import Contact

def index(request):
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()[:5]
    return render(request, 'about/home.html', contacts)

def all_contacts(request):
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'about/all.html', contacts)
```

template:

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
    {{ contact.name }} | {{ contact.number }}
{% endfor %}
```

I gets this error:

> TypeError at /  
>  cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to
>   a sequence

```
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

What this error is about? 
whats wrong with my code? 
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation :

> Optional arguments
>
> **context**
>
> A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is callable,
>   the view will call it just before rendering the template.

So :

```
def all_contacts(request):
    context = dict()
    context['contacts'] = Contact.objects.all()
    context['otherStuffProcessedByTheTemplate'] = …
    # etc…

    return render(request, 'about/all.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to explicitly creating a `context` as done by @Bogey Jammer,
you can add the `contacts` to the `context` by specifying it in a dict as an argument to `render`:

```
def all_contacts(request):
   contacts = Contact.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'about/all.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```